# Microsoft Teams: Posting direct message to user in response to message in channel

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

New to Teams bot, and I am trying out the samples with python botframework,

**What I need?**

- With teams Messaging Extension, added an action menu for message, on click it shows a input dialog - *this is done.*
- User selects a message in a channel, and use the above action menu, once the user inputs a value in the dialog, the requirement is to send him a direct (private) message - *this is not done*

**What I tried**

Tried using proactive message from samples,

The proactive message can be done via either of the below methods in BotFrameworkAdapter

- create_conversation
- continue_conversation

but both methods needs a conversation reference, but in my case, I will not have a conversation reference, as the user would interact for the first time only in action menu in channel.
What i have is the from_property ( which holds all details of user) in turncontext,  but didnt find the write api in framework to send direct message to user with this values.

Answer (score 0):

Your Teams application would need to contain both the Message Extension and the Bot itself (registered in the Bots section). As a result, when they install the app, to get the message extension, your Bot will be installed at the same time. Good practice is to send a ["welcome" message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) anyway, which you do by hooking into the "OnMembersAddedAsync" event - see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#Team-Member-Added). In that event you immediately have access to everything you need for a proactive message (ServiceUrl, ConversationID, TenantID,..)

Comment: 1. Yes i created the bot in app studio and it contains both bot and message extension
2. but again, here message is sent with turn_context.sendactivity, which cant be used in my case as it just sends it to the channel thread not as direct message to user

Comment: turncontext.sendactivity definitely wont work - it uses the current context, which is the team+channel - I thought you were create_conversation or continue_conversation? Have a look at this point, it might give some interesting background to what you're trying to do (send a message to one conversation from within another) - it gives some background to how the messages are sent/received: https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work

Comment: This is what i understood from your article and other answers,

The bot framework requires users to message the bot before the bot is able to message users to prevent spam bots. You can send welcome messages to the user when they join the conversation, but in the Teams channel the user still has to message the bot before the bot can send a welcome message.

So there is no way, i can send a message to a user, before his first interaction.

Comment: So, the main point I was trying to make so far, is that you need to be sure to send to the -correct conversation-. Simply replying to the incoming activity won't do that. With regards to -getting- the conversation details, the easiest way is just to get them when the user installs the app, as you've said. If this is not possible, or not yet happened, then you can "auto-install" the app on demand for the user. It requires calling the Graph API, and currently is only available on the Beta endpoint.

Comment: (ran out of space) It is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-add-teamsappinstallation?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http , and also note you need the user ID, but you'll have that from the original message.